# Python script freezing program

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, cmd

I am new here but I recently have been messing around with python and Qt. My situation is that one of the scripts I call does a lot of OS commands and basically waits for a response. When I call this script it runs fine and acts accordingly except in my main program the screen is frozen until I exit out of the cmd. I think this is because mt script just waits there for a response, is there anyway to make it so that even though the script is running and executing(waiting for response with cmd) the user can still use other aspects of the main program?

Comment: provide a [mcve], also review about QProcess.

Comment: using multithreads / multiprocessings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you will need to use threading. Threading allows multiple functions to executed at the same time. Check out this link [Python threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).
You'll just have to run your side script on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it, This solved my problem!